# Set dynamic error message in Yup validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yup

I am struggling with the Yup validation on a React project. I want to validate an object and set a custom error message based on custom conditions:

```
this.validationSchema = Yup.object({
  myValidation: Yup.string().trim.test("test_myValidation", "", function (value, context) {
    let error = false;
    let myMessage = "";
    if (this.state.myCondition1) {
      myMessage = "error message 1";
      error = true;
    }
    if (this.state.myCondition2) {
      myMessage = "error message 2";
      error = true;
    }
    return error ? this.createError({ message: myMessage }) : true;
  }),

  //other validations

})
```

what I'm getting is this error in console:

```
formik.esm.js:783 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
at yupToFormErrors (formik.esm.js:783:22)
at eval (formik.esm.js:307:19)
```

I've tried using arrow function ( `(value, testContext) =>` ) instead of `function (value, context)` and then calling `testContext.createError( ... )` after reading another question here but i'm getting the same error.